# How to Specify File Type and Size Limits With PHPMailer Mailing Multiple Attachments

Tags: phpmailer

Can someone please let me know using the `PHPMailer` how I can specifiy the limit of size and type of attachment?

For example if I want to enable Only PDF file to be attached and with limited size how I can update this part of the code?

```
foreach ($_FILES["attachment"]["name"] as $k => $v) {
    $mail->AddAttachment( $_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"][$k], $_FILES["attachment"]["name"][$k] );
}
```

Here is the entire code

```
<?php
require('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
    $mail->Port     = 465;  
    $mail->Username = "YOUR USER_NAME";
    $mail->Password = "YOUR PASSWORD";
    $mail->Host     = "YOUR HOST";
    $mail->Mailer   = "smtp";
    $mail->SetFrom($_POST["userEmail"], $_POST["userName"]);
    $mail->AddReplyTo($_POST["userEmail"], $_POST["userName"]);
    $mail->AddAddress("RECIPIENT_EMAIL");   
    $mail->Subject = $_POST["subject"];
    $mail->WordWrap   = 80;
    $mail->MsgHTML($_POST["content"]);
    
    foreach ($_FILES["attachment"]["name"] as $k => $v) {
        $mail->AddAttachment( $_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"][$k], $_FILES["attachment"]["name"][$k] );
    }
    
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "<p class='error'>Problem in Sending Mail.</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p class='success'>Mail Sent Successfully.</p>";
}   
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't PHPMailer's responsibility – it's up to you to control the size and type of files *before* it gets to PHPMailer.

First of all, you're using a very old and unsupported version of PHPMailer, so upgrade to [the latest version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps).

Secondly, your handling of uploads is unsafe. Follow [the PHPMailer file upload example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps) for how to do it safely.

In your form, set a hidden field named `MAX_FILE_SIZE` **before** your `file` input, set to whatever maximum size you want to impose:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="123456">
```

This can't actually control the size of submissions, but by convention, browsers will use it to reject oversize files *before* they are submitted, saving the user considerable hassle.

*After* validating the $_FILES element you're looking at (with `move_uploaded_file`, as in the example), take a look at the size of the submitted file by looking at the size element:

```
if ($_FILES['attachment']['size'] <= 123456) {
    //We know file is under our size limit
```

To check the file type, extract the extension from the provided filename:

```
if (pathinfo($_FILES['userfile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION) === 'pdf')) {
    //We know file has a `.pdf` extension
```

For good measure, you could also check that the provided file type is what we want too:

```
if ($_FILES['userfile']['type'] === 'application/pdf')) {
    //We know file has a PDF MIME type
```

After checking all of those things, you're now safe to pass the validated file to PHPMailer:

```
$mail->addAttachment($uploadedFilePath);
```